# Why is a Dockerfile for an ARM-based Go app dropping "linux_arm" from runtime path?

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I am using a Dockerfile as follows to create an image using `docker build` on a Raspberry Pi, which is ARM-based. But it is failing at the `COPY --from=builder` step because it cannot find the path "/go/bin/linux_arm/example-experiment", and a couple of debug "ls" commands at the end of the "builder" stage show that the actual path created in that stage was "/go/bin/example-experiment (i.e. missing the "linux_arm" directory level) :

```
FROM golang:latest AS builder

ENV GOPATH $GOPATH:/go/src/example-experiment
ENV GOOS linux
ENV GOARCH arm
ENV GOARM 7

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install git

ADD . /go/src/example-experiment/
WORKDIR /go/src/example-experiment

RUN go get -v ./...

RUN go install
                                                                                                                                                                            
FROM scratch

# Copy the static executable.
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/linux_arm/example-experiment /go/bin/linux_arm/example-experiment

# Run the application's executable binary.
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/linux_arm/example-experiment"]
```

I tried replacing `RUN go install` by `RUN go build` but the same thing happened.

Possibly this is more about Go than Docker. But a colleague running a build with the same Dockerfile finds it completes with no errors, and presumably their base image uses the same version of Go.

The actual error is as follows :

```
Step 19/20 : COPY --from=builder /go/bin/linux_arm/example-experiment /go/bin/linux_arm/example-experiment
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/36eef7ea57e69d51c9f00dc151fde8c0e7cd38a2ca3e51505c153594f57db5ba/merged/go/bin/linux_arm/example-experiment: no such file or directory
```

I thought Go was supposed to create a runtime path /go/bin/$GOOS_$GOARCH/... which in this case is /go/bin/linux_arm/...

Answer (score 0):

Been doing some more digging on this ..

Apparently the way `go install` works is that native binaries go to $GOPATH/bin, and cross-compiled binaries to $GOPATH/bin/${GOOS}_${GOARCH]

So if the image is built on Windows (as my colleague did) then an ARM build counts as cross-compiled, and the bin directory is set to /go/bin/linux_arm, which is what the later `COPY --from=builder` command expects, so everything works.

But when (as I did) the same build is done on a Raspberry Pi, the binary path is assumed to be /go/bin, and the `COPY` command cannot find the directory it expects.

The solution, which I have confirmed works, is to define the binary path so it is the same in either case, by setting the GOBIN environment variable as :

ENV GOBIN /go/bin/${GOOS}_${GOOARCH}

So for once I have answered my own question.

(I also added a "go" tag to the question, as this is not really a Docker issue as such. But I left the "docker" & "dockerfile" tags in case anyone else building go-based Docker images encounters the same issue.)

Comment: Consider using Go modules. Try to avoid `go get` and `go install` now as there's modules. You'll notice it'll make it a lot simpler for you! And for cross-compilation, use `GOOS`, `GOARCH` envs.